# How can i move away from a Partial<T> to T without casting in Typescript

Tags: typescript

General Typescript question say I iterate over an array which i know its content and apply a reduce to get an object back which I do know the type
for instance:

```
interface IMyInterface {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
}
const result: IMyInterface = ['a','b','c'].reduce((acc: Partial<IMyInterface>,val)=>({...acc,[val]: 1}), {});
```

Now that wont work because result is expected to be `Partial<IMyInterface>` which makes sense, considereing TS cant tell the content of the array will produce the "full" object.
However What do I need to do so that result can be of type IMyInterface without the need of `as IMyInterface` ?

Here is a repl https://repl.it/@Sudakatux/KaleidoscopicGraciousApplicationpackage

Thanks in advance

Comment: With `reduce()`?  There's probably nothing better than a type assertion; in order for this to work, the callback would need to be generic `<K extends keyof IMyInterface, T extends Partial<IMyInterface>>(acc: T, val: K): T & Record<K, number> => ...` but the type system lacks the ability to express the higher-order operation of specifying `T` and `K` for each element of the tuple type `["a","b","c"]`.

Comment: You can [unroll](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CSyDeAoZQ5OALmRAFcBbAI2gG4CiazLaGnCFXq6pGAvnhgUQCMMAD2IZDAAUADzIZMASlzIhYdAAcUAUQU64IACYAeACoA+ZAF5khsFERgryCAshmAzslAw0MgAqsgA-BoA2gDS-jIA1hDokjAhALpkwTFpmsisEABu0AA0yDaMImIS0sg+EGAAClCSOlalsZ7epn6JyamWpQBqHl4QvmXZ1nKSNABWZAPIvWTRpQVwADZkg6oknMQ+dVBgfjOz-n6GxmbuAGTIAEoQCJJQFqvIg9a2+ETI03MDsQQOggU8Xm9zB8vqpIr0cg51htBHgNvVkFAID4KBswGQGnBjsBNuYVLYHDgBBU5JjsbjVPRkAB6JkeKDNKB4OqNZo6GlYnFgUoAIjgwtKAEYGcJ+XSwAzmazoByufUmi1ZYKRTRxcgpdTaYKFSy2Srueq+YbcSKELr9TKrfLGSbJPE4Og8J6gA) it, but not in a loop or `reduce()`.

Comment: @jcalz I dont understand how thats related. sorry. and in the unroll example there is a cast to any and then a cast from any to Record

Comment: That's not [important](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CSyDeAoZQ5OALmRAFcBbAI2gG4CiazLaGnCFXq6pGAvnhgUQCMMAD2IZDAAUADzIZMASlzIhYdAAcUAUQU64IACYAeACoA+ZAF5khsFERgryCAshmAzslAw0MgAqsgA-BoA2gDS-jIA1hDokjAhALpkwTFpmsisEABu0AA0yDaMImIS0sg+EGAAClCSOlalsZ7epn6JyamWpQBqHl4QvmXZ1nKSNABWZAPIvWTRpQVwADZkg6oknMQ+dVBgfjOz-n6GxmbuAGTIAEoQCJJQFqvIg9a2+ETIZ5FejkHOsNoI8Bt6sgoBAfBQNmAyA04MdgJtzCpbA4cAIKnIYXCEap6MgAPSkjxQZpQPB1RrNHT42HwsClABEcDZpQAjMThEzCWBiWSKdBqbT6k0WgKWeyaFzkLy8QSWcLyZTxXSpYyVQj2QgFUr+bqhST1ZJ4nB0HgbUA) to the unroll example, sorry

Comment: My point was that there's no way to tell the compiler how `reduce()` forms a chain of accumulator types that change from one loop to the next.  The generic callback type can at least represent the change of type, which works if you unroll it via `setProp()` or something like that, but there's no way to give a type signature to `reduce()` or any loop structure that will understand that you start with `{}`, then have `{a: number}`, then have `{a: number, b: number}`, and finally have `IMyInterface`.  Each step is representable, but the whole thing is not.  Type assertions are probably necessary.

Comment: Here's a more [analogous unrolled example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCerzXk5AbwChkzk4AuZEAVwFsAjaAblPMerqdfbIS4NmUNgF9iMWiARhgAexDIYACgAe1DNlyxEEAJRFk4hAoDOYZAkbIAvH2QAeANLIIqyCAAmp5AGsImHIwaFg4kDpIADTIACqu7hBePgAKcFCycAA2DppheLoAfAXKiAKx0QBuWdROepT25LHIAGTIAEoQJlCeztHcwgW2g8qEyAB0E6XRANpVmQC61ACMRnrEEspWm4zbI6LRAERwB3qHjCeHCCd6LI3EQA).  That just works, but only because the compiler sees each step happen separately.

Comment: Thanks for the example, was kind of what i was looking for

Comment: Why the downvote. The question seems pretty clear. and the answers go to the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer here is: you pretty much need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) because it's not possible to have the compiler figure out that what you're doing is safe.

---

The much longer answer: in order to even begin to let the compiler know what's going on, you need the callback to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).  Here's one way to type it:

```
const cb = <K extends keyof IMyInterface, T extends Partial<IMyInterface>>(
    acc: T, val: K): T & Record<K, number> => ({ ...acc, [val]: 1 })
```

That type signature says that the `cb` takes two parameters, `acc` and `val`.  The `acc` parameter is of generic type `T` which must be assignable to `Partial<IMyInterface>`, and the `val` parameter is of generic type `K` which must be assignable to `keyof IMyInterface`.  Then the output of the callback is `T & Record<K, number>`: that is, it is an object with all the keys and values from `T`, but it also has a definite `number` value at the key `K`.  So when you call `cb()`, the return value is potentially of a different type from that of `acc`.

This gives enough information to the compiler to allow you to avoid type assertions... but only if you perform the `reduce()`-like operation with `cb()` manually, by unrolling the loop into a bunch of nested calls:

```
const result: IMyInterface = cb(cb(cb({}, "a"), "b"), "c"); // okay
const stillOkay: IMyInterface = cb(cb(cb({}, "a"), "c"), "b"); // okay
const mistake: IMyInterface = cb(cb(cb({}, "b"), "b"), "c"); // error! property "a" is missing
```

Here you can see that the compiler is really looking out for you, since if you call `cb()` in the wrong way, you get an error telling you so.

Unfortunately, [the type signature for `Array<T>.reduce()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1186),

```
reduce<U>(
  callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: readonly T[]) => U, 
  initialValue: U
): U;
```

is insufficient to represent the successive type narrowing that happens each time `callbackfn` is called on elements of the array.  And as far as I can tell, there's no way to alter it to do this.  You want to say that the `callbackfn` type is some crazy intersection of types corresponding to how it behaves for each successive member of the array, like `((p: A, c: this[0])=>B) & ((p: B, c: this[1])=>C) & ((p: C, c: this[2])=>D) & ...`, for generic parameters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, etc., and then hope that the compiler can infer these parameters from your call to `reduce()`.  Well, it can't.  The kind of [higher order inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22617) just isn't part of the language (at least as of TS3.7).

So, that's where we have to stop.  Either you can unroll the loop and call `cb(cb(cb(...`, or you call `reduce()` and use a type assertion.  I think the type assertion really isn't all that bad; it's meant specifically for situations in which you are smarter than the compiler... and this seems to be one of those times.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCerzXk5AbwChkzk4AuZEAVwFsAjaAblPMerqdfbIS4NmUFsmIBfYggD2IAM5hkCRsgC8yADwBpZBAAekEABM5yANYRM0mGiw5IsRBAA0yACq6DEY6YAKcKDBgOAAbDQxsXEckAD4YgAo+CgQBd1cAN1DqLQBKag8AMmQAJQgZKCNtV25hGLU6+MJkADpWxARXAG1MkIBdagBGZHEc4ilZBWQoCDlaELBqCPs8JzUlRnjlTY3CcVcAIjh9nIPGY4OEY9EAemvkaTM4THH5RQVgEJCAeUfMRbsovgUOotqCdntkIdzpDLidIWccjc7g8ni9JvRgAo4BZ-pEHEC1mDto0IfsEadoftYUjdFAoNIoABCZAAB3pLOgYEwkKOyExyAxcjkoAA5mMgA)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same thing and have been able to get things working as needed by casting the `acc` as the desired interface, and the initial value as `any`:

```
const result= ['a','b','c'].reduce((acc: IMyInterface,val)=>({...acc,[val]: 1}), {} as any);
```

This should set `result` to be of type `IMyInterface` without raising tslint errors.

Comment: thanks for the response. So im looking for something that does not require casting. That includes casting to any

Comment: The funny thing is. it would be actualy wrong because on the first iteration acc is empty and we are saying there is type IMyInterface which is not it is actually a Partial<IMyInterface>

Comment: Yes, technically it's wrong inside the reducer, but this has done the job when used in these specific cases, where I'm transforming a known quantity with a very simple, terse reducer. Since the function is so short, I've given up on finding a more "correct" solution - I just care about the final result being typed correctly. In more complicated cases, though, I'd agree that having the correct typing inside the function would be great.