# Typescript - Create custom type from common properties of an Array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

I have an array of objects, which have a common key "foo" and I am trying to create a custom type out of this property. I am not looking for its value that I can get from a reduce but more its Type. Here is a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGArApsALgRmgbwFDQIjTDQEthoAzAe2ugF4doAnZAEwFdhlmB9agHbIAXDnwEJ0eGGYZRaZh2TjoAXzUrqSVGl4ZeAW2RoAFtTYAKAJQ5VuO7lCQYCFOgBMYiURLkqtBiZWTm4%20NAB3alE8SQlpZndRSjAQCGUJdTsJLTddd0NjM0sbbDsHJyg4bXQAZi9CYjIKGjpGbBZ2Lh5eU1YRetj4mvlFdIJMzWrdGoLTc2tbe1xHQSJoAwBPAEFmZjANwIBtVx0MABoq3PcLk9roAF0AbmXgVbQOkJ4YRk2dvY2AHTBLoWCxgYDAC7ADjMGz0AB8Aw6aBhAiRkgBmPBkJUsUxAOhzABLVxZQupSsz1wAHpqR8uswYGgNgAHZCBUo0ukAUQAHmz0OxoMy2cKTCRoABJaDhMACd5oOgcNLQcBoHjQUho0zs15sdm4EXsvkC9VsWAcNAsy0AFVZ7LauOBoX4QmiuLiMjkUloIGQcpUqjOKmd3QiUXRBHiiR91D9AYywYkobCJj67tiUZkw1j8YEgfsQA) to the TypeScript playground with a reproduced example and the expected output Type I need to retrieve:

```js
class Object1 {
  static foo = { reducer_one: { a: 1 } }
  object_1_method() { }
}

class Object2 {
  static foo = { reducer_two: { b: 2 } }
  object_2_method() { }
}

class Object3 {
  static foo = { reducer_three: { c: 3 } }
  object_3_method() { }
}

const myArray = [Object1, Object2, Object3 ];

const reducers = myArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return {
        ...acc,
        ...cur.foo
    }
}, {});
const myArray = [Object1, Object2, Object3 ];
```

I am trying to get a reduced object type gathering all the different **foo** properties of all the initial objects in the array.

```js
const finalObject = {
   reducer_one: {...},
   reducer_two: {...},
   reducer_three: {...}
}
```

I tried to reduce the array to an object with the objects' respective foo property in order to retrieve its type but the output type of the reduce remains an empty object.

Thanks in advance for your help. Hope the description of the issue is clear enough

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mx67Kw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  Also, when you say "I tried to reduce the array" you should probably show that in the example code.

Comment: It sounds like you care about the type and not the value, but you should be explicit about this so that you don't get answers like the one below showing how to call `reduce()` in JavaScript.  Anyway, I think [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQeQ7w) might be what you're looking for.  If so, I'm happy to write up an answer if you update your code example here to be a good [mre], maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N537ZW)?

Comment: You are right sorry about that, I should have been more explicit about it. I updated the post and added a TypeScript playground link to reproduce the code and the expected type. Thx

Comment: @jcalz thx for sharing your solution. The Reproduced type seems to be exactly what I needed to retrieve and there is also a lot of TypeScript tricks that I can learn from this. Thanks a lot for your help on this one !!!

Comment: Could you update the plaintext of the post to replace `...` with whatever you want?  It might be a few hours before I get the time to write up the answer explaining how that `ReducedType` works and why the compiler can't infer that automatically.

Comment: Just changed the `...` with actual values. Thx again for your help this is great material to improve with TypeScript skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will pretty much need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler what type `reducers` is going to be.  Let's call this type `ReducedType` with the understanding that we will have to define it at some point.

---

If you use `Array.reduce()` or any other method to walk through an array and add properties gradually, the compiler can't really follow what's happening.  See
[How can i move away from a Partial<T> to T without casting in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58981956/how-can-i-move-away-from-a-partialt-to-t-without-casting-in-typescript) for a similar issue.

You could try to use [the `Object.assign()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to do this all at once:

```
const maybeReducers =
  Object.assign({}, ...myArray.map(cur => cur.foo)) // any
```

but the [TypeScript library typings for `Object.assign()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cec2fda9a53620dc545a2c4d7b0156446ab145b4/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L313) operating on a variadic number of inputs just returns a value of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), which doesn't help you either.

Let's stick with `reduce()`:

```
const reducers = myArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    ...cur.foo
  }
}, {} as ReducedType);
```

So we're asserting that the initial `{}` value passed in is `ReducedType`.  This assertion is sort of a lie that eventually becomes true.

---

So how do we compute `ReducedType` from the type of `myArray`?  Let's look at `myArray` with [the TypeScript `typeof` operator]:

```
type MyArray = typeof myArray
// type MyArray = (typeof Object1 | typeof Object2 | typeof Object3)[]
```

First we want to get the type of the elements of that array.  Since you get elements from an array by indexing into them with a numeric index, we can take the `MyArray` type and [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with [the `number` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean):

```
type MyArrayElement = MyArray[number]
// type MyArrayElement = typeof Object1 | typeof Object2 | typeof Object3
```

That's a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the three class constructor types.  From there we want to get the type of each union member's `foo` property.  We can do that with another indexed access (which distributes across unions):

```
type MyArrayElementFooProp = MyArrayElement["foo"]
/* type MyArrayElementFooProp = {
    reducer_three: {
        c: number;
    };
} | {
    reducer_one: {
        a: number;
    };
} | {
    reducer_two: {
        b: number;
    };
} */
```

So that is looking closer to what you want... except it's a union and you really want the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of them, since your `ReducedType` should have all of those properties.

(And no, I don't know why the compiler chooses to order the union with `three` at the front.  It doesn't affect type safety at any rate.)

There is a way to [transform a union into an intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) using TypeScript's [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), shown here without additional explanation (see the other q/a pair)

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type IntersectionOfFoos = UnionToIntersection<MyArrayElementFooProp>
/* type IntersectionOfFoos = {
    reducer_three: {
        c: number;
    };
} & {
    reducer_one: {
        a: number;
    };
} & {
    reducer_two: {
        b: number;
    };
} */
```

This is exactly the type we want, although it isn't represented too pleasantly.  A type like `{x: 0} & {y: 1}` is equivalent to but less pleasing than `{x: 0; y: 1}`. We can use a simple [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to convert from the former form to the latter:

```
type ReducedType =
  { [K in keyof IntersectionOfFoos]: IntersectionOfFoos[K] }
/* type ReducedType = {
    reducer_three: {
        c: number;
    };
    reducer_one: {
        a: number;
    };
    reducer_two: {
        b: number;
    };
} */
```

And we can stop there if you want.  It is of course possible to put this together in a single type alias, although it's less obvious what we're doing:

```
type ReducedType =
  typeof myArray[number]["foo"] extends infer F ?
  (F extends unknown ? (x: F) => void : never) extends
  (x: infer I) => void ?
  { [K in keyof I]: I[K] }
  : never : never

/* type ReducedType = {
    reducer_three: {
        c: number;
    };
    reducer_one: {
        a: number;
    };
    reducer_two: {
        b: number;
    };
} */
```

---

So there you go, now the compiler knows the type of `reducers` strongly enough to let you index into it:

```
console.log(reducers.reducer_one.a.toFixed(2)); // 1.00
console.log(reducers.reducer_two.b.toFixed(3)); // 2.000
console.log(reducers.reducer_three.c.toFixed(4)); // 3.0000
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBGArApsALgRmgbwLAChpoI0w0BLYaAMwHtboBeHaAJ2QBMBXYZVgfVoA7ZAC4WYcVgC+0aQSK0kqNPwz8AtsjQALWhwAUAShbz8ZgqEgwEKdACYcC4qQpU6DZtjaceffmgA7rTi3vDijrJmisro-Paa2nqGJt5mFvhWUHCxaADMToQuZJQ09Ews7Ny8ArrsYizA4gVRzkp2qnmJuvrGpgQZwMIk0BoAngCCrKxgYxUA2rYqGAA0OR32a0voeQC6ANwElsNoo7PwyABKvjUwjM7baAB01uQA5kIG2NJrT3-jUxmYyeGjAAAcDMAuKwmAA+aBQ1hPDxGEwAejR0DAQjGR3waDGYOQ0AAspNprMKgSibRqKNyUCCBjoNTiWTAZTmAZWbT1stoAAfFmE5C8x6OIU8umPPJGea7PGs0kM2YAURAyC0QlOzHZFLG8yEXA0F1YCvwzKVeqB6s1yG1VJFYtyWElTuluQlwppHo6eUVIuVHLGtq1aAAYvQAAqsWhgirWtUasPzABEHlT5rRACpvWyVSHk-aI9HY-GvM4iFU-LUdPVQpWiE2mtAjSa+IcikRpJ3ZEK8F2fNV-MIGgOmxOseI26bOxOewNBYUJ9WagFgg3BxPwq3jbPGwvzNBs2iA0ToABVITkYQAFVoAEltXwICob0IADwX+H3IoGC-QMgAAeaD2hwMDYnMAD80AGAA1uIF4mIw8IAG60OQHDQNOyCoXwJjAaBQjgbB8HiOQQjUHw0APshaEYRwJgwQ+2GtrhfBnsST6gawr7oO+sDUJGtB3Je153o+z68W+wgfomhZ2tqwkxnGsJMrmSrcS+MlCIJwmieOTarv4dTIGOjYTi2M4dgevbQAAZMuRk3COIibpOTaSLu7asHOTaHrIjmGVWLm1BuTkeTu1m+bZi4nniBBKtcw4cLeIoAAxMM43jzAA0tAFHQHByBjLyWnSfxwh6fQEC7OI5V8RQVVCTVeW7HI6l5tAyV+KlGUVMFQ41gEdZme5HkItOe42YOh4rqFghuRFk5edFfndutQ1rkEITLduU0+ZtAXHqe+CJYGPW8H156-kQUr0sGhrTWaaYZu1hFgTAFFUTC4bQFBzgGH9H3ETAXBCHBQi0IEQj-bBQHiOGdHQOhmGsSIeGsARIGfYDCMFZR1G0XCKMMf92XQHlBNFSVZV1TRbUdUUOGY+j7GsHiOZdZdnBpTdy3GbW9Z7c2B37rNm2C4t5lbp5YszfOksLTt42RfLMUS3Fp14kMQgjILokAvqTzGQYBhgMAwBrIiyOGewaDQrDg1-C8lsrI2LuIsi9DOOkazfFiMA89dyBGJ2OvDLQGpPCAtBvAYBsmwto4vE8aC0OG5BAZwBj2Ki+zQMyGBPOl6XHHrUfIDHccJ6FEBJ8OYW0E88BpxnWc57KYeF5i9gl6X5cQJX1fx4nUumVXwBt5n2eGAALPnPfQHk-cD-gQA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving the issue and explaining the whole process. That s very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```js
const finalObject = myArray.reduce((obj, clazz) => {
   Object.keys(clazz.foo).forEach(prop => {
      obj[prop] = clazz.foo[prop];
   });
   return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain what your problem is in the question?