# TypeScript - Dynamically create object interface based on function parameters

Tags: typescript, types

I'm working on a small project that requires me to create lists of products more or less like so:

```js
let products = createList(
   new Product('product1'),
   new Product('product2')
)
```

At some point I need to access some product - let's say it's the `product1`. I'd do it like so - `products.list['product1']` and then do some stuff with it. Each product in the list has a `name` property that's derived from the first parameter in the constructor. At this moment `products.list` is using a basic string index signature and what I'd like to acheve is so that intellisense could suggest that the `list` object has properties `product1`, `product2` and so on. Similarly to how request parameters in express are done:

[image]

I inspected express' type declarations, read the TS docs on utility types, especially on the Record type as it seemed it was what I've been looking for but couldn't figure out what to do after all.

It's not impossible that I just searched for the wrong stuff. I'd really appreciate if somebody pointed me to the right docs.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8oorW) what you're looking for? If so I could maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  Note that it helps for you to present a [mre] with something like a definition for `Product` and anything else necessary as background info.

Comment: @jcalz This is actually exactly what I was trying to achieve, though I'm not 100% sure what's happening in the code on line 7 specifically so a simple explanation would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to possibly work, the `Product` class needs to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` property.  Otherwise, the compiler will only know that the `name` property is `string`, and any hope that the keys of `createList()`'s output would be strongly typed would be gone.  So let's say `Product` looks like this:

```
class Product<K extends string> {
    constructor(public name: K) { }
    size = 123;
    cost = 456;
}
```

(Caveat: this definition is quite simple, and `Product<K>` is currently [*covariant*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411491/2887218) in `K`.  So a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `Product` types will be assignable to a single `Product` type; e.g., `Product<"product1"> | Product<"product2">` will be assignable to `Product<"product1" | "product2">`. The code below relies on this assignment succeeding.  But if `Product<K>` were complex enough to be *invariant* in `K`, this assignment would fail. This could be worked around by changing the code, but I won't digress further here worrying about it.)

Now we can define `createList()`:

```
function createList<K extends string>(...products: Product<K>[]) {
    return products.reduce(
      (a, p) => ({ ...a, [p.name]: p }), 
      {} as { [P in K]: Product<P> }
    );
}
```

The function accepts a variadic number of arguments of type `Product<K>` for some `K`, which will turn out to be the union of all the `name` properties of the individual `Product`s.  We use `products` array's [`reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build up the desired object, adding a property with key `p.name` with a value of `p` for each product `p` in `products`.

The return type of `createList()` is `{[P in K]: Product<P>}`, a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which has one property `P` for every member in the `K` union.  The property with key `P` will be of type `Product<P>`.  The compiler is [not smart enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58981956/2887218) to understand or infer that `reduce()` actually produces a value of this type, so we use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just pretend that the empty initial value passed is of that type.

Let's see if it works:

```
let products = createList(
    new Product('product1'),
    new Product('product2')
)

/*let products: {
    product1: Product<"product1">;
    product2: Product<"product2">;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKBOB7AJgV2AFwDwGloFMAPDfAO2Rgg3gEtSBzAPmgG8AoaT6YRUq+dBkTwAFAAdUAIxA1g0UmAC2+AFzQcASlbQAvhy4QaAL3zQAvNACMAJgDMAbn2ceVc9AAsAVgBsjvQDNUUkwaXm54fDASABkaKlwCYjIKaH46JhEAOmyxJDRMCDUEFEFcRgBtAF0tdi5oCIxUeFJoXJKCzIj8-BERMAAaVq0zZhEWaGzMgehysUyFZUq1MV0NQZYdaEhtcthoOnUluDzS2GYdDTY9NhB8DFaTgrdgCKj8WKoRJ3l8AHdj9oYEQAcja+QwlmBa2+pD+APBILBgmsULYlzYAHoAFS3e5IgpqWpcfEQoqPbAAIhJlgpjEcdRJ1jJgKwVPJ1lpfmgWIxbDYPD4iFumRAiHo4nJEEy1PmSnw6KAA)