# How to perform a type-safe object map in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typing

I'm trying to write a function in `Typescript` that maps an object, while guaranteeing that it keeps the same keys. I've tried various approaches to this, but haven't found a way that works:

```
function mapObject1<K extends PropertyKey, A, B>(
  object: { [P in K]: A },
  mapper: (value: A) => B,
): { [P in K]: B } {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object)
      .map(([key, value]): [K, B] => [key, mapper(value)]),
  ); // error!
  // Type '{ [k: string]: B; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in K]: B; }'
}

export function mapObject2<K extends PropertyKey, A, B>(
  object: { [P in K]: A },
  mapper: (value: A) => B,
): { [P in K]: B } {
  const result: { [P in K]?: B } = {};

  (Object.keys(object) as K[]).forEach((key: K) => {
    result[key] = mapper(object[key]);
  });

  return result; // error!
  // Type '{ [P in K]?: B | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in K]: B; }'
}
```

In `mapObject1`, using `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()` causes the type of the keys to be converted to `string`. In `mapObject2`, `result`'s keys have to be optional since it starts out empty, causing `Typescript` to not be able to recognize that all of the same keys as in `object` are present. How should I approach solving this issue?

Comment: You can't really make it type safe for the *implementer* of your function.  The compiler can't verify that `Object.keys()` or `Object.entries()` returns the types you think it does (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/2887218), nor can it understand that a `.forEach()` loop does everything you need it to do to convert a `Partial<T>` to a `T`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58981956/2887218.  So you will need to take care that you implement properly and use type assertions or the like to suppress the compiler errors.  Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, there are some unconventional names in this code you might want to change; `K` is generally reserved for something which is itself keylike, but you seem to be using it as an object type (since you write `keyof K`).  Also, mapped types iterate over type parameters, not key names, so `key in XXX` is unconventional, and should be `Key in XXX` or even `K in XXX` (or `P` for "Property").  But since you're only using the keys of `K`, you should probably not use that object type.  So I'd suggest [edit]ing your example code to look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXzn9m).

Comment: @jcalz I did not know about type assertions, they seem very useful - I guess Typescript cannot know everything by itself. Thanks for the suggestions for the types as well, they fixed the next issue I had where the function would not correctly infer the generic types. If you put your comments into an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: Okay, I will write up an answer when I get a chance. Do you mind if I [edit] your code to use more conventional names and remove the other issue with `keyof`?

Comment: @jcalz Not at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the TypeScript compiler is unable to verify that the implementation is safe for a few reasons, and the most pragmatic way forward is to take special care that your implementation is written properly and then use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that the values have the types you claim they have:

```
function mapObject1<K extends PropertyKey, A, B>(
  object: { [P in K]: A },
  mapper: (value: A) => B,
): { [P in K]: B } {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object)
      .map(([key, value]) => [key, mapper(value as A)]),
    // assert --------------------------------> ^^^^^
  ) as { [P in K]: B }
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- assert
}

function mapObject2<K extends PropertyKey, A, B>(
  object: { [P in K]: A },
  mapper: (value: A) => B,
): { [P in K]: B } {
  const result: { [P in K]?: B } = {};

  (Object.keys(object) as K[]).forEach((key: K) => {
    // assert -------> ^^^^^^ (you already did this)
    result[key] = mapper(object[key]);
  });

  return result as { [P in K]: B };
  // assert --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

That all compiles fine.

---

The reasons the compiler is unable to follow the logic:

- The typings for [the `Object.entries() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)` and (the `Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) do not restrict the keys of `object` to just your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `K`.  Object types in TypeScript are not "sealed", so objects may have more properties than the compiler knows about.  So the compiler only returns `string` for the key type and `unknown` for the value type.  See [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/2887218) for more information.

  So some of the errors you're getting is the compiler trying to save you from problems like this:

  ```
  interface Foo { x: number, y: number, z: number }
  const obj = { x: Math.LN2, y: Math.PI, z: Math.E, other: "abc" };
  const foo: Foo = obj; // this assignment is okay
  const oops = mapObject1(foo, num => num.toFixed(2)); 
  /* const oops: { x: string; y: string; z: string; } */
  //  num.toFixed is not a function !!!
  ```

  The value `foo` is of type `Foo` because it's fine for there to be extra properties.  But then you hit a runtime error inside your mapping function.  In practice this is often a fairly unusual situation, so maybe you're convinced that this is an acceptable risk. If so, use the type assertion and move on.  If not, then you will need to rewrite your function to accept an explicit list of keys to transform. But I consider that out of scope for the question as asked.
- Even if the compiler knew/thought that `Object.keys(object)` returned every single key, there's no way for it to understand that looping over these keys and setting a property in the return object will cause the return object to be promoted from a partial object to a full object.  Doing so is *safe* (to the extent that `Object.keys()` won't miss any required property keys), but verifying that is beyond the compiler's reasoning abilities.  See [How can i move away from a Partial<T> to T without casting in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58981956/2887218) for more details. This is a great place to just use a type assertion and move on.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcDyAjAVgU2gEYAeAaUXwA8p8wATAZ0QAUAnOdfNqATzPy8ANIgCCIgEIA+ABQAoRIjh5CUAFyIA3ogDaLRDCRkAuhtGIAvkIUoMXNhpkA3VABsQ+MwEpEAXimIEtZeGtp6BkamgZZaNmz4UCBsSDgE0AB0wBzIAKJgUGww+Izyioqpqul0BUUlymlQXjZliOlo6DIyOgDWgiIu7vjGPv66vcK26PbObh6IqMyiXsPWLQD0a-OMjNxQiAC0h0fHJ6dnxwEAetfXNj4LWrr6hogmGhKWNhs3P79-iCRDlsdjw5BY5HJQJBYAhJhVoAAmciUGh0JisDj2PgCCbiQKyGz1VShJ4RV5RcxWGzteyOAYebx+AJBOQhR7hF5vaIWWKKCAIRh7eKMECudTs56RAD87xivi0FgA3BDFDJ4VB0uM6ipoPdmGQdMNMnA2DlUBAABadcYaMgjAKaZqIDbA3YHU5XX6IGS8OAgeaueKoei8RD0GD0RBQC0wRhNFrC0VQHqCYx+SbTInQFO8YbKxQWLzKuIJJJIRNirYSslcj5Kr6bBYgvaHT1-ds3MEQwy0NjAc34RAAMTgcEeVA0YBAyGw3BEvEn09nbBEAC9FzPuJ9+WBBUo8OntBPEABZVDR9IAGQAcgj5xozxeWABJNcP88W9I5ERwaPcDQAESoNgEAAZYyo7nuwCjhoI5jvK9SKs6mzRrGwIwAA5mAyDVAYzBwN0qC8HIkF7KO6DMPK7TqkQMjQXAIhTsgTKIEx6RQHAQ4wFQ+D0DICJeEWiByGsABUiCkUonCMCSx6CoUYAYUhC6IPJhhKYg66qTUilITyolrCJmyALwbgClO6x07sZx3G8XhrG-vMiBQtA8BIAAhB5chAA)