# Error When Doing Recursion on Children in Type Generic

Tags: typescript

I need to write a function that generates an annotation for an object by adding an access control field `$` to each node in the object tree.
To annotate an object `{ field: {...subFields} }`, we need to get `{ field: { $: 'view', ...subFieldsAnnotated } }`.
To annotate arrays and their elements, whenever there's something like `{ arr: [...elements] }`, we should replace that with `{ arr: { $: 'view', $items: [...elementsAnnotated] } }`.

I'd like to make the following work:

```js
type Annotated<T, NewFieldName extends string, NewFieldValue> =
    T extends Array<infer U>
        ? // Wrap arrays in an object with '$items' and the new field.
          {
              $items: Array<Annotated<U, NewFieldName, NewFieldValue>>;
          } & {
              [K in NewFieldName]: NewFieldValue;
          }
        : // Check if T is an object (but not an array, which is handled above).
          T extends object
          ? {
                [P in keyof T]: Annotated<T[P], NewFieldName, NewFieldValue>;
            } & { [K in NewFieldName]: NewFieldValue }
          : // Directly create an object with the new field for primitives.
            { [K in NewFieldName]: NewFieldValue };

type Access = "none" | "view" | "edit";

type Accessor<T> = Annotated<T, "$", Access>;

function isObject<T>(value: T): boolean {
    return value !== null && typeof value === "object";
}

// this is okay
const emptyObjAnnotated: Accessor<{}> = {
    $: "view",
};

// this in not
function getAccessor<T>(value: T, access: Access): Accessor<T> {
    if (isObject(value)) {
        if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
            // >> ERROR: should extend T with '{}' or 'object'
            const keys = Object.keys(value) as (keyof typeof value)[];
            // >> ERROR: Type '{ $: Access; }' is not assignable to type 'Annotated<T, "$", Access>'
            return {
                $: access,
                ...keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
                    if (isObject(value[key])) {
                        return {
                            ...acc,
                            [key]: getAccessor(value[key], access),
                        };
                    }
                    return {
                        ...acc,
                        [key]: { $: access },
                    };
                }, {}),
            };
        }
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            // >> ERROR: Type '{ $: Access; $items: { $: Access; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Annotated<T, "$", Access>'
            return {
                $: access,
                $items: value.map((child) => {
                    if (isObject(child)) {
                        return getAccessor(child, access);
                    }
                    return { $: access };
                }),
            };
        }
    }

    // ERROR: Type '{ $: Access; }' is not assignable to type 'Annotated<T, "$", Access>'
    return { $: access };
}

// // for testing purposes
// 
// type ExampleType = {
//     id: number;
//     name: string;
//     tags: string[];
//     details: {
//         description: string;
//         images: {
//             url: string;
//             alt: string;
//         }[];
//     };
// };
// 
// const example: ExampleType = {
//     id: 1,
//     name: "name",
//     tags: ["tag1", "tag2"],
//     details: {
//         description: "description",
//         images: [
//             {
//                 url: "url",
//                 alt: "alt",
//             },
//         ],
//     },
// };
// 
// const access = getAccessor(example, "view");
// 
// console.log(access.id.$); // 'view'
// console.log(access.details.$); // 'view'
// console.log(access.details.images.$items[0].url.$); // 'view'
```

The issue seems to be that when recursing on the children, the current version of the type generic `Annotated` doesn't accept the type `{ [K in NewFieldName]: NewFieldValue; }`.

The algorithm itself appears to be correct, so when I change the function's signature to

```js
function getAccessor(obj: any, access: Access): Accessor<typeof obj>
// .....
```

it gives results as expected, but then, of course, I'll lose all the type notation, so I won't be able to reference my fields based on the data structure according to `Accessor<T>`.

Any ideas on how can I salvage types here?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-IKivmWbrAO2qjPKo7zJFiQKhD8xiqNEa68DoDBgKAW4RMOfSYB0M69v2dTLIOl6aOkHSlvWpBThBWbQWigQhL0C5Liua5QEIEDAARRb9jgCh7geWgECgPZFvh4mcMeeazn2fADmRGgUACkKbtusRCbMZJkkptQqVCT4wEilRYsZXRafIOl6Ts7wKEoACiABKTkbk5HScEkiAfgUNIcICHopKkxF5EGaSgakqqaMhcCobyIDFlAWGMpU8WcJZ5K+NwkLxX+v4AgB5K7BcDwxnZjkuW5h7gNAwVQBRsm9vMGZ5LB8IoEWFBCHAKBhPihSIIUNVpDh4rYPgZaTtOUkKJFMZQNet4hFs83kR0YlyXgUVNJUu1pZUtoYLIBaQpCG0EPFunKEoK2rfpqnqeCwAZbs8UXNZt13dsi13jZX07LtlTndt-17G9HRcTxUlBi9b2iVJZJbaD2yZiDOxmsjC3cUtf3I4DwOY7Ur18sKmoNRtvYZkjmOo-9ywEMRiMg7TKNsgZkLmcYpmcJzIAZR9IPlVAzmue5WjDXVDW8ZwzUtNknAdGTklyc1yzFarrXcO1nXdb1-XAINnYjaKuHjeOU2NXOc0xj9y1o2tvhSdTd1y+0-4mpUDAoGAp0YhQtBXTd9tNOzj2MpCfsB7pn2E7bnHcdLMORxg8NyWSpXIxjyNx0rjtyRmGercsTPzSzKyNJBDjvCLVXi7mkvK01LVwdrnBdT1fXQAbQ316No4TROU6W5ws2NDn9XrVJBcQaoUHuGYYXoLwghCFAYC3mAiCcIWs9Gw5LCMGA+I4MNJafRQGAdO+DBhJYhc9UwHn8CvheoEICs8M-wjq40GDcSg-sP4x00H-TgToKAYVXHAJ+AhhCFwcBQL2XEgEg1vNQGBL8QYyGABguBbI1YlQrosVGSEUJxFYIffEHR96UIgCfXMZ9GgXw6AARmdj6cYlEH4QFog4N+H9diljfiwoeQiUBCAAEylmlL-f+gDFZslAeAyBa5KJKIECouAvDtiIPEYWDouwQbAKpGgyiaDtF3WwZRbBFjHj0zZDItUW0SExVQhTIsKh45QzkjDCh6F8Tjmoo2dOs9XFnggJUagiAhBnSkqZKo6R06uHcKkIJkUwn4kidE2JclKh-1QIAyoiTmrvFSQ2dJKFwlZJie4qM+SAHUCjLo5BRSsg5F2AABguJUNBRSkmlLSUAA)

Comment: • Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that demonstrates what your issue is and does not have other problems when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. Right now things [look weird and inconsistent](https://tsplay.dev/NroVlm) and you don't seem to be asking about any of that. • What is the actual issue? You say "the trouble seems to be that the end-to-end type safety is broken".  What does "end-to-end type safety" mean, and where exactly is that issue showing up? Is there an error where you don't expect one? The lack of error where you do expect one? The [mre] should make it obvious.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code was a hot mess, and my wording was vague at best. I've done some edits, should be reproducible now.
What I meant by "losing end-to-end" is that within the algorithm, despite doing all the type checks, it still breaks the type generic, so that it'll keep giving an error.

Comment: Your `Accessor<T>` type is a complicated conditional recursive mapped type and inside the body of `getAccessor()` it's a complicated *generic* conditional recursive mapped type. There's essentially zero hope that the compiler could follow your implementation and verify that it matches the type. Try to envision how the compiler would need to be written in order to do so; it would need to do some fairly miraculous analysis at each step. (more...)

Comment: (...continued) Even the "basics" don't currently work in TS, considering that `isObject(value)` only narrows `value` but has no effect on `T`. My suggestion here is to not even try to care about accurate type checking inside your function. Just verify it to your own satisfaction and then use some form of type loosening to suppress errors, like a one-call-signature overload [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/wX04ow).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, that seems like a solid suggestion! I'll accept your answer when you post it.
I might have gone overboard with typings. I guess it's best to stay minimalistic when using generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `getAccessor()` function, the intended return type `Accessor<T>` type is a complicated [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that uses [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), and recursion.  There is essentially no hope that the compiler could look at some code and accurately decide whether or not some value can be safely assigned to `Accessor<T>` for generic `T`.

Currently it fails even at the most basic part of your expectation, which is that it would recognize, say, `isObject(value)` as affecting `T` in some way. As of TypeScript 5.4, though, we don't have [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) or [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). [Control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) like `if (isObject(value)) {⋯} else {⋯}` will only affect the apparent type of `value`; it has no effect on `T` itself. So `Accessor<T>` is not affected.
This might change someday (indeed it is on the TypeScript 5.5 roadmap as per [microsoft/TypeScript#57475](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57475) but for now it's a limitation.

Even if that were resolved, though, you'd get stuck.  The compiler can't understand that [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) will slowly build up an object into something assignable to a mapped type. That would probably require something like *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) to even *express*.  See [How can i move away from a Partial<T> to T without casting in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58981956/2887218) also.

I could go on but I don't think it's worth it. Essentially the compiler is unable to follow almost any of what you're doing.  So it doesn't even really make sense to attempt to make it do so.

---

The normal approach to situations like this, where you have a complex generic call signature and complex implementation, and the compiler can't match them up, is to take on the burden of verifying the implementation yourself (i.e., read it carefully and test it carefully and convince yourself that for all use cases you care about the output is assignable to the return type) and then loosen the compiler checking wherever necessary to suppress errors.

The easiest approach here is to split the function into its call signature as seen from the outside, and a looser implementation as seen from the inside, and write it as a single-call-signature [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
// call signature
function getAccessor<T>(value: T, access: Access): Accessor<T>;

// implementation
function getAccessor(value: any, access: Access) {
  ⋮ same impl
}
```

The implementation shouldn't have to change much at all; I've given `value` [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to tell the compiler not to bother itself with type checking.  Once you do this, callers will still see the strong generic typing you want. And the implementation errors go away.

No, it's not perfect, but I doubt we'll ever see a version of TypeScript capable of following the logic in your function and automatically verify that it matches a generic recursive mapped conditional type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdnA9sAhsCATAPAFQDRQByEA7gGICWEANhoSgLbQQAe6cGAzlJ8AE4U4AcwLFyVWgDUU1AK4QAfFAC8AKCgaoOKK3ZdYfPihBZBAMwh8oAVQXrNAfigB6Z1ADqRsFBSHj3QR84KEQAIwArCABjYCgSCmAACygAcgASBIgGThSgjCgk6DhSKDMJDAA6ew0Ab2rNDQz0bIAuAyMTeCRUdGxrUVJKGjpGCAHxYek5RQUAbnqAXygAMig6hoaAbQBpKECxIdp6JgBdNoPyqfl5hoX6ttcoAGFE6IBrPbMtPe4UYLDIjEoAAKUKyWLdII+PwgAgkRIUKLJCjcRJ-DDUTA+UKIABuEAAlFUGtpdBAONwAdFgPUnOsNhpNgAFPbBN4QECIL44M6wBDINCYXDMk7jQ4jJhiy4yeRzRYrNZQHasoiDcrHCC8i6TGXQO4NB5uAAiFD41OoICgUTNgqhVKB8SSBVeUGKJFK5VKiCsYAEDASFHxnGJmhqSt2+zVww1WqjUl1UAW81UoEgsCiUQgnG4yigACIkMU81AAD753FUEjFst5zAJPPJ1PQGAZrOcb24JS5roC3q4Ah5tJ5ggtzPZuWqMyyOAxCiIYIogDyEWpneBuN1bRwBLaOMQmL+a3qZuAsj4wQ30ygAEJlLm4LJqNQVqsm1yoJf5Co7-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-RQs70ND3twJanblwRt2YqFJ9HDXJmcIZiA4kVWwX0xf+5-dQiBCLlfE2UqGkYKLg3ApFfikNO7kv4VB-n-K+wY+722oMGYBsxQGpAgVA9smJYG-3-kJCoSCHY2X9lmCon1sibAAAwnAqCHChIDHjgMrCkIAA)

Comment: Thank you so much, @jcalz, I've learned a lot about TS today!
Naturally, It's best to avoid overly complicated type manipulation, but, if all else fails, the **single-call-signature overloaded function** seems like a great way to "black-box" messy implementation and still retain the ability to use types outside it.